# Animation in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files, units

How to animate like the animation in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_1Hzl9o5ic) at t = 58 onward. Any suggestion or any guide.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please ask the separate questions for each effect you want to achieve.

Comment: The best way to use this site is by asking focused questions. We have no idea if what you need is help with the texturing of a particular object, or modeling, lighting, moving the camera or rendering...  As it stands your question sounds more like a tutorial. Tutorials are out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Animation is a very vast subject and requires a lot of practice , patience and know how of blender simulator, giving a full answer here is not possible, however a very loose guidance is given below.

the grains on the ground, rock like structures and DNA spore look a like are straight forward modelling.

to create a moving ground/belly , you need to follow the http://blendtuts.com/tutorials-list/afterearthmap tutorial

for DNA spores to move towards rocks and go back, use boids (Basically allows you to simulate horde/flocks etc and can be moved back and forth between targets).
Basics explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJT9zRi56w0

Comment: You might find useful information in Neil Hirsgi's [PDF tutorial](http://gryllus.net/Blender/PDFTutorials/10ASwarmOfBees_iTunesU/SwarmOfBees.pdf) on modeling a swarm of bees.